# Can I calculate the length of each line in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, vim-plugin

I have a file below.

```
My
first
name
is
Kim.
```

And I wanna find the way(vim plugin, regular expression or vim function) that make this file below.

```
My      2
first   5
name    4
is      2
Kim.    4
```

Is there any method to calculate the length of each line in vim?
I don't want to achieve this via perl/ruby script or script development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
:%s/\v(.*)\zs/\="\t".strlen(submatch(1))/
```

To understand how is this supposed to work: `:help \v`, `:help \zs`, `:help s/\=`, `:help strlen()`, and `:help submatch()`.

Depending on what you use this for, if you work with wide characters you might need to replace `strlen()` with `strwidth()` or `strdisplaywidth()`.  They might make more sense as "line length".